# fxpmath : substract two unsigned into a signed result

Tags: python, data-conversion, fixed-point

```
import numpy as np
from fxpmath import Fxp as fxp

t1 = fxp(4, False, 9, 3)
t2 = fxp(5, False, 9, 3)
inter1 = fxp(0, True, 9, 3, raw=True)
inter2 = fxp(0, True, 9, 3, raw=True)

inter1(t1 - t2)
inter2(t1.get_val() - t2.get_val())
```

inter1 is equal to 0.00 because the two numbers used in the calculation are unsigned. The only way I found to have the correct result is to use numpy values (from get_val()). Is there a best way to do this ? I don't want to put t1 or t2 in signed.

Comment: I don't have the module installed to test this, but I think `inter1(t1.like(inter1) - t2.like(inter1))` would work.

Comment: Its working, thank you.Somebody in my company answered me like that : in an FPGA, when there is a unsigned number in a subtraction, the element is cast in signed (sign bit added). I use fpx Lib to simulate the behavior of an algo in an FPGA, so that's all i need to know.

Answer (score 0):

The solution proposed by @jasonharper is right, but it might not be what you're trying to model.

When you do:

```py
t1.like(inter1) - t2.like(inter1) # t1_signed - t2_signed
```

> fxp-s10/3(-1.0)

You are converting `t1` and `t2` to **signed** just as `inter1`, so you are performing a **signed subtraction**, and I think it's not what you want to model.

Casting an *unsigned* fxp to a *signed* one force *msb* (most significant bit) to `0` if you keep size. That will generate a wrong calculation if `t1` and/or `t2` are equal or bigger than *signed upper limit* (31.875 for your example). For example:

```py
t3 = fxp(48, False, 9, 3)
t4 = fxp(49, False, 9, 3)

t3.like(inter1) - t4.like(inter1) # t3_signed - t4_signed
# t3_signed = fxp-s9/3(31.875) because overflow clipping
# t4_signed = fxp-s9/3(31.875) because overflow clipping
```

> fxp-s10/3(0.0)

If you are trying to model a **unsigned subtraction** and then storing that value in a *signed* fxp you have to use **wrap overflow**. Additionally, if you wanna keep size at *subtraction* (or other operation) you have to set `op_sizing = 'same'`:

```py
t1 = fxp(4, False, 9, 3, overflow='wrap', op_sizing='same')
t2 = fxp(5, False, 9, 3, overflow='wrap', op_sizing='same')

t1 - t2
```

> fxp-u9/3(63.0)

If you check the binary format, you'll see that the subtraction is correct:

```py
(t1 - t2).bin(frac_dot=True)
```

> '111111.000'

Look that the *msb* is equal to `1`, so when you cast this value as a *signed* fxp this will be negative:

```py
# cast from unsigned to signed keeping raw binary value
inter1('0b' + (t1 - t2).bin(frac_dot=True))
```

> fxp-s9/3(-1.0)

Now,

```py
t3 = fxp(48, False, 9, 3, overflow='wrap', op_sizing='same')
t4 = fxp(49, False, 9, 3, overflow='wrap', op_sizing='same')
inter1('0b' + (t3 - t4).bin(frac_dot=True))
```

> fxp-s9/3(-1.0)

Finally, let me write a more elegant way to work with same fxp sizes along your code:

```py
from fxpmath import Fxp

# Set a template for new Fxp objects
Fxp.template = Fxp(dtype='fxp-u9/3', overflow='wrap', op_sizing='same')

inter1 = Fxp(None, signed=True) # overwrite template's sign

t1 = Fxp(4)
t2 = Fxp(5)
inter1('0b' + (t1 - t2).bin(True)) # or inter1('0b' + (Fxp(4) - Fxp(5)).bin(True))
```

> fxp-s9/3(-1.0)